# pressing CTRL - K doesn't delete characters in vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

CTRL-K works in other terminals (deletes like from the point of cursor)
but it says ***"Ctrl K Was pressed and waiting for second chord"***

Upon pressing Ctrl-K twice it says ***Not a command***

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this shortcut has not been set in VS code keyboard shortcuts.

So, Navigate to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts and in the search bar search for `workbench.action.terminal.clear`

If the Key Binding is already available you may use that or insert your own key binding.

**Below are the steps to change key binding:**

1. Double click on the `Terminal:Clear` row and enter the key binding. Hold the CTRL key and then enter K and then press enter. Your new key binding will now be displayed.
2. It is preferable to change the when expression as well, just Right click the `Terminal:Clear` row and select `Change When Expression` option. Enter `terminalFocus` in the text box then press enter. That is all, your new shortcut will work as expected.

Comment: sounds good, doesn't work